# How do I fill the value of an input element with Mechanize?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, mechanize

How do I change fill the value of an input element with Mechanize?

What I want to do is set a ranger http://d.pr/i/nMuM to be between 2010 and the default value of 2014 so the correct trucks show up for parsing. Would that be possible?

I'm following the example [here](http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/GUIDE_rdoc.html) but it doesn't seem to work.

This is the code:

```
require "mechanize"

@url = "https://www.kleyntrucks.nl/vrachtwagens/trekker/"

a = Mechanize.new do |agent|
  agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
  agent.follow_meta_refresh = true
end

a.get(@url) do |page|

    bouwjaar_range_field = page.search("#imprp0")

    bouwjaar_range_details = bouwjaar_range_field.search(".details")

    input = bouwjaar_range_details.search("input")[0]

    input.value = "2010"

end
```

This is the output:

```
/Users/username/Dropbox/Development/Rails/folder/lib/tasks/experiment.rb:20:in `block in <main>': undefined method `value=' for #<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x007fd4ab0fd9a8> (NoMethodError)
    from /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/mechanize-2.7.3/lib/mechanize.rb:442:in `get'
    from /Users/username/Dropbox/Development/Rails/folder/lib/tasks/experiment.rb:10:in `<main>'
[Finished in 1.9s with exit code 1]
```

`pp input` gives me the following output:

```
#(Element:0x3fe33c82ab68 {
  name = "input",
  attributes = [
    #(Attr:0x3fe33c869430 { name = "type", value = "hidden" }),
    #(Attr:0x3fe33c8692a0 { name = "name", value = "slider_from" }),
    #(Attr:0x3fe33c869278 { name = "value", value = "1968" })]
  })
```

`puts input` gives me the following output:

```
<input type="hidden" name="slider_from" value="1968">
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's lots of problems here. To start, your form is not a form, it's an input. And not even a "form" input, but a "dom node" input. Once you understand the difference, find the form and set the value with:

```
form['key'] = 'value'
```

Comment: That's correct, it's not a form but an input. Any way I can fill the input with `2010`?

Comment: You don't want to manipulate the dom (unless you're doing something weird), you just want to set the form value.

Comment: What I want to do is set a ranger http://d.pr/i/nMuM to be between 2010 and the default value of 2014 so the correct trucks show up for parsing. Would that be possible?

Comment: Yes but that has nothing to do with forms.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like elements have a `set_attribute` method. You should be able to do

```
form.set_attribute 'value', 1970
```

and get the proper result.

That feels overly complicated to me, but it should solve your immediate problem. (I've worked with Mechanize a lot, although not much recently.)

Comment: Using `puts form.set_attribute 'value', '2010'` gives me a NoMethodError: ``experiment.rb:19:in `block in <main>': undefined method `set_attribute' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)``

Comment: I'm using Mechanize, the `set_attribute` method might be for Nokogiri?